# Color correction/grading then editing in Premiere

Tags: premiere, color-correction, color-grading, davinci-resolve, speedgrade

I'm trying to incorporate color correction/grading into my Adobe Premiere CC workflow. I have an x-rite color checker, and have had some success calibrating in Davinci Resolve Lite, but I don't want to render everything in Resolve, just to have to rerender/edit in Premiere. Is it possible to simply output the calibration information (Looks & LUTS?) created from the color matching into Premiere so it's just another effect being rendered on my clips?

If not, is there a way to use Adobe Speedgrade CC to match the colors from the x-rite color checker and then send it back into Premiere without having to render all the clips before other editing?

I guess the final option would be to edit and render in Premiere and then use Davinci Resolve as a post-processing calibration step and rerender afterwards, but this seems like it wouldn't be as convenient and would be very time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In turns out all I had to do was grade in DaVinci Resolve and right click on the graded clip's thumbnail in the color environment and select Generate 3D LUT (CUBE).

[image: DaVinci Resolve exporting 3D LUT]

Then in Adobe Premiere CC add the Lutemtri effect to an adjustment layer, expand basic correction, Browse for Input LUT.

[image: Premiere CC importing 3D LUT]